# Google maps api issue broken duplication of shapes after zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing a polygon using javascript, sometimes when I change the zoom of the map the polygon appears twice but it goes away after zooming in/out or dragging the map. The image below shows the issue with what seems to be an incomplete version of the polygon redrawn on the left.

[image: Incorrect polygons]

After zooming in and out the polyon displays fine as you can see below.
[image: correct polygon]

Is this a bug in the google maps api? It's not a huge issue as it doesent happen all the time and goes away after playing around with the dragg/zoom of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you experiencing the issue in Chrome browser? If so, there is a bug report in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242

Please star the bug to add your vote and hopefully Google will fix it soon.

**UPDATE**

As stated in Google issue tracker, the issue was fixed in Chrome 60. The corresponding bug was marked as Fixed on August 9, 2017.

Comment: Thank you I checked out this post I believe this is the same issue I will have to keep an eye on that link you provided.

Comment: This issue has now been fixed in chrome Version 60.0.3112.90